# Unicode superscript j missing (ⁱ found)

Tags: unicode

Please help find superscript j Unicode character code, if it is present. If not, do you know why?

I look up on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters). There is ⁱ, but no j.

Comment: Try `U+02B2`, Reference [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spacing_Modifier_Letters)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, there's [U+02B2 MODIFIER LETTER SMALL J](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/02b2/index.htm). That said, as the name implies, it's intended for cases where a superscript 'j' serves as a sort of diacritic (e.g. in IPA, where it denotes that the previous consonant is palatalized). Using it as a *pure* superscript would be cheating; see ["Why doesn't Unicode have a full set of superscripts and subscripts?" in the Unicode FAQ](http://www.unicode.org/faq/ligature_digraph.html#Pf8).